# вызвать экшн контроллера из юнит теста через http запрос

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь вызвать экшн контроллера из юнит теста через HTTP запрос

```cs
[TestMethod]
async public Task TestHttpRequest()
{
    await new HttpClient().PostAsync("http://localhost:60872/Home/About/", null);
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Путь, порт правильный, но возникает ошибка:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:60872`

Что делаю не так, можно вообще так вызвать? Есть подозрение, что IIS express в этот момент не поднят - не получается это проверить

Comment: `конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение` значит сервер поднят, но ненастроен принимать подключения по данному IP адресу. Порт указан при этом верно.

Comment: Кстати, вы уже не первый вопрос оформляете, почему такое небрежное отношение к оформлению кода? Вам прияно читать такой код?

Comment: виноват - не получается быстро нормально оформить. очень мало времени